# Special character on y-axis of matlab figure

Tags: matlab, figure

I need \hat{g} to appear on the y-axis of a matlab figure. Is there a way to do this easily?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab: Adding symbols to figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825453/matlab-adding-symbols-to-figure)

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825453/matlab-adding-symbols-to-figure

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm trying to use a LaTex string for an axis label in MATLAB and get a number for no apparent reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548895/im-trying-to-use-a-latex-string-for-an-axis-label-in-matlab-and-get-a-number-fo)

Comment: If you want to use latex code more than in just this one label I can suggest to use `set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex');` (and ofc `$\hat{g}$` as label); otherwise follow the discussions linked above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An exmaple:

```
plot(1:10,rand(1,10))
set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex');
ylabel('$\hat{g}$');
```